# How to compute an average runtime?

Tags: math, average, weighted-average

I have a set of programs and for each program, it contains many subprograms, of which, one subprogram has the longest runtime. My goal is to calculate the the average ratio of (longest runtime)/(entire program runtime).
I want to know what is the right way to do so.

```
> program  longest runtime     entire runtime    ratio
> 
> 1        10 secs             50 secs            0.2
> 
> 2        5 secs              40 secs            0.125 
> 
> 3        1 secs              10 secs            0.1
> 
> 4        20 secs             80 secs            0.25
> 
> 5        15 secs             20 secs            0.75
```

So I want to see how much percentage the longest runtime takes of the entire runtime. 
There are two ways to do so:
1: compute the ratio for each program and then calculate the average of the ratios.

(0.2 + 0.125 + 0.1 + 0.25 + 0.75) / 5 = 1.425 / 5 = 0.285

2: compute the sum of longest runtime and then divided by the sum of entire runtime.

sum_longest = 41 secs

sum_entire = 200 secs

average = 41 / 200 = 0.205

which way is correct?

Comment: The second way computes different statistic than the first one. I'd go with the 1st.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that your latter answer (getting .205) is correct, because your first method does not take the weights (i.e. how long it takes each program to run) into account.